# how to retrieve target security group for a SharePoint list item?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, target-audience

I am developing a web part in C# which is reading the contents of a SharePoint list. 
I can retrieve the values in all the fields I need, except the Target Audience field (which uses AD security groups).  I have tried various ways to access this e.g.

string myItem = Convert.ToString(ListItem.properties["Audience"])

but all I get is null returned.  I can see that a target group has been stored in the fueield for thwe item when I edit the item in SharePoint.

How can I retrieve the contents of this field using code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not using the `Properties` of the `ListItem`, but the fields themselves.

In the "Target Audience" field you have some GUIDs stored as strings, these you need to retrieve like so:

```
//use the FieldId enumeration for system fields
string audienceID = item[FieldId.AudienceTargeting] as string;
string newID = audienceID.Remove(36); //retrieve just the first guid
Guid audienceGuid = new Guid(newID);

AudienceManager audienceManager= new AudienceManager(SPContext.Current.Site);
Audience audience = audienceManager.GetAudience(guid);
```

afterwards you might want to look at `audience.GetMembership()`.